# How can I send a variable with a type Apex-Defined to subflow?

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

How can I send a variable with a type Apex-Defined to subflow ? Or this impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at least according to Salesforce help page. In the Salesforce help [Considerations for the Apex-Defined Data Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_apex_data_type.htm&type=5) article  has a Section on Input and Output values and it says:

> An Apex-defined variable value can't be set or stored outside the flow. 
>   The value can't be passed to a Subflow element.

Comment: Thanks so much.